# Importing OpenCV in Chrome Extension: cv is not defined

Tags: javascript, opencv, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load OpenCV in my chrome extension but it comes up as undefined although other libraries get loaded just fine.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Screenshot App",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This extension automatically takes screenshots of the screen",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "tabs","downloads"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["scripts/*"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "use_dynamic_url": true
        }
    ],
  "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
    },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/content.js","scripts/html2canvas/html2canvas.js", "scripts/tessaract/tesseract.min.js","scripts/opencv/opencv.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "camera.png",
    "32": "camera.png",
    "64": "camera.png",
    "128": "camera.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "scripts/service-worker.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

I have also tried initializing it through inserting the script in the webpage itself. The onload function gets called and when I try to access cv inside it, it still throws `ReferenceError: cv is not defined`

content.js

```
async function initializeCV() {
  if (initializingCVPromise) {
    return initializingCVPromise;
  }

  initializingCVPromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (document.getElementById(CONSTANTS.scriptIdCV)) {
      log("Already loaded script");
      resolve();
    } else {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.id = CONSTANTS.scriptIdCV;
      script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("scripts/opencv/opencv.js");
      (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);

      script.onload = async function () {
        log("Loaded OpenCV Script");
        log(script.src);
        onOpenCvLoaded();
        resolve();
      };
    }
  }).finally(() => {
    
  });
  return initializingCVPromise;
}
```

Comment: Remove the entire initializeCV, move "scripts/content.js" to the end of the list, then reload the extension and simply use the globals exposed by the prior scripts directly e.g. `cv` and whatnot.

Comment: @wOxxOm it now throws ```Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'``` and still ``cv is undefined```

Comment: Add `"world":"MAIN"` to your content_scripts declaration, remove all script names except "content.js", keep your initializeCV to inject these scripts into the page, see also [this answer](/a/9517879) for more info.